# mysql_fetch_assoc() gives me the wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

When I make the query bellow I can do a password check and the password and it works. 
How ever, when I try to extract the row id called id it returns 0 when it should be something else. And when I print the password the same way it prints two digits instead of the string I was hoping for.

I more or less a beginner to PHP but maybe someone could see whats wrong with my code?

```
$sql = 'SELECT pass FROM tbl_user WHERE email = "'.$email.'" LIMIT 1 ;';
$selection = mysql_query($sql);

$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($selection);
$user_id = $r['id'];
print "user id is: " + $r['id'];
print "user id is: " + $r['pass'];
```

Comment: Note, when using `LIMIT`, it is advisable to specify an `ORDER BY` as well, so your results are predictable.  `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1`

Comment: Theoretically `LIMIT` would be redundant because I would assume `email` should be unique in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only `SELECT`ing the password. Change your query to

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, pass FROM tbl_user WHERE email = "'.$email.'" LIMIT 1 ;';
```

With regards to printing it, instead of using `print`, use `echo`. Also, instead of `+`, use `.` to join strings together:

```
echo "user id is: " . $r['id'];
echo "user id is: " . $r['pass'];
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I will flag it as the right answer in 6 minutes when its possible.
Another question, I am checking the response on an app and not a browser. Do you still think echo is the better choice for showing the response?

Comment: `echo` and `print` are identical, except that `print` returns true/false on whether it managed to print it out - in ALMOST all cases, "being able to output something" is taken as given, so `echo` is used. If there's a reasonable chance that `print` may fail, use `print` and you can check to make sure it was successful.

Answer (score 3):

You only select the `pass`, not the `id`

Use this query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, pass FROM tbl_user WHERE email = "'.$email.'" LIMIT 1 ;';
```

Answer (score 3):

You're only selecting `pass` in your query; so the `id` isn't returned.